# Conditional Loop in Elixir

Tags: loops, dictionary, foreach, elixir

I've started studying Elixir, but I'm struggling with the functional paradigm shift from OOP.

So the exercise I'm doing asks me to return the correct string format, converting DNA to RNA.

For example: `RnaTranscription.to_rna('ACTG')` should return `'UGAC'`.

This is what I have so far, but I don't know how to proceed.
How should I take each element and substitute them?
I thought about using String.replace(dna, "A", "U") for each one but it's not DRY.

```
defmodule RnaTranscription do
  def to_rna(dna) do
    map = %{"A" => "U", "C" => "G", "T" => "A", "G" => "C"}
    dna
    |> String.split("")
    |> Enum.map(dna, substitute(dna, x))
  end

  def substitute(x), do: x -> [ map[x] | substitute(tails) ]

end
```

Comment: `'ACTG'` is a list, not a binary aka string in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

In the first place, in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) one should distinguish double-quotes denoting string and single-quotes, denoting charlist. The latter is effectively *a list*, not a string.

```elixir
iex|1> is_list('ABCD')
#⇒ true
```

---

This *exercism.io* example helped you already because it asked to translate *charlists*. That said, one might go with [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) on the input (or with [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension.)

```elixir
map = %{'A' => 'U', 'C' => 'G', 'T' => 'A', 'G' => 'C'}

Enum.map('ACTG', fn c -> map[[c]] end)
#⇒ ['U', 'G', 'A', 'C']

for c <- 'ACTG', do: map[[c]]
#⇒ ['U', 'G', 'A', 'C']
```

As we might see, in both cases we need to access the element in a map as `map[[c]]` and the result is a list of lists, That is because `'A'` is a list on its own, having one single element `?A == 65`.

```elixir
[65] == 'A'
#⇒ true
```

To fix it, we might start with the more suitable mapper, mapping chars to chars instead of charlists.

```elixir
map = %{?A => ?U, ?C => ?G, ?T => ?A, ?G => ?C}
for c <- 'ACTG', do: map[c]
#⇒ 'UGAC'
```